# embed a YouTube 'like' button on a website

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to display YouTube's like/dislike buttons and subscribe channel features with the video on my site even if the user is not logged in? I found that I can use an iframe and css to crop out the like button from the video page on YouTube and display it in a borderless iframe on my webpage, but I don't need to it in this way .
Also I've checked this player demo https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo
but the controls needs to be loggedin to appear. 
I'm using this library https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/codeigniter_library

Comment: can you share it please? I'm interested :)

Comment: Hey @aadiahg what is the solution? share it please.

Comment: Yes please share the answer. Thanks

Comment: This is shaping up to be one of the biggest mysteries in SO.

Answer (score 0):

For the like/dislike buttons, see the YouTube Video `rate` API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/getRating

Your visitor will not need to be 'logged in' but your application must be.

The call had a quota impact of 50 as of July 2023.

Comment: quota impact increased to 50